# How to handle terminal nodes in Monte Carlo Tree Search?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, montecarlo

When my tree has gotten deep enough that terminal nodes are starting to be selected, I would have assumed that I should just perform a zero-move "playout" from it and back-propagate the results, but the [IEEE survey of MCTS methods](http://mcts.ai/pubs/mcts-survey-master.pdf) indicates that the selection step should be finding the "most urgent expandable node" and I can't find any counterexamples elsewhere. Am I supposed to be excluding them somehow? What's the right thing to do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you actually reach a terminal node in the selection phase, you'd kind of skip expansion and play-out (they'd no longer make sense) and straight up backpropagate the value of that terminal node.

From the paper you linked, this is not clear from page 6, but it is clear in Algorithm 2 on page 9. In that pseudocode, the `TreePolicy()` function will end up returning a terminal node v. When the state of this node is then passed into the `DefaultPolicy()` function, that function will directly return the reward (the condition of that function's while-loop will never be satisfied).

It also makes sense that this is what you'd want to do if you have a good intuitive understanding of the algorithm, and want it to be able to guarantee optimal estimates of values given an infinite amount of processing time. With an infinite amount of processing time (infinite number of simulations), you'll want to backup values from the ''best'' terminal states infinitely often, so that the averaged values from backups in nodes closer to the root also converge to those best leaf node values in the limit.